# Amazon EC-2 Can't edit files in filezilla tried updating permissions in instance via putty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have tried to update permissions but failed (used a few methods mentioned here)

I can upload the new file to just the ec2 user folder the file is called query_ip_whitelist.txt I need to place this file in folder also in the ec2-user folder called teamspeak3-server_linux-amd64 which will overwrite the old file within the folder any advice on how to do this within putty would be great.

I only have basic skills so if you can be descriptive as possible id highly appreciate it as I'm a bit slow ha!

Edit-The File i need to edit's permission is ROOT

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the file you want to edit is root-owned, you cannot edit it unless you have access to the root account on the instance in question. Assuming you do have that, one option, given your currently described access, would be to upload the new version of the file using SFTP (i.e. Filezilla) to any location, then move the file on the command line using SSH (i.e. Putty).

So, upload the file to the instance, then log in via SSH and do something like this:

```
$ su -
$ mv /path/to/uploaded/file /path/to/file/you/want/to/overwrite
```

Comment: Hey Oliakaoil thanks for replying, Hey Oliakaoil thanks for replying, when I tried what you had said I got this error returned the file is deffo there so not sure...

Comment: '# mv home/ec2-user/query_ip_whitelist.txt /home/ec                                                                                                                                                             2-user/teamspeak3-server_linux-amd64/query_ip_whitelist.txt
mv: cannot stat ‘home/ec2-user/query_ip_whitelist.txt’: No such file or director'

Comment: You're missing a forward slash at the beginning of the path, for your first parameter of your mv call. That might help.